# Free VB 6.0 Decompiler?

Tags: vb6, decompiling

Is there such a thing as a VB 6.0 decompiler?

If so are there any free products that do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try your luck on the [Visual Basic Decompilers page](http://www.program-transformation.org/Transform/VisualBasicDecompilers) of the [Program Transformation](http://www.program-transformation.org/) wiki.

Answer (score 3):

**VB ReFormer** and **VB Decompiler**. They are very easy to use.

Comment: Are those free? Can you provide links?

Answer (score 0):

VB6 compiles to machine code, so all you would be able to do is disassemble it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler

There are some tools that claim to parse and translate the machine code, but I have never tried those.

Comment: Compiling to machine code is an option. You can also compile to P-code. Decompiling P-code is more plausible, though I don't know whether any of the decompilers out there actually work.

Comment: I totally forgot about P-Code. :) I've done almost zero VB6 programming. Mostly used it to test C++ COM components.

Answer (score 0):

Vb 6 compiles to native EXE files, not P-Code. Therefore you'll be hacking ASM.

Comment: Incorrect, it's a compiler option. You can compile to native code or P-code.