# Decompiler for Visual Basic 6 program?

Tags: vb6, decompiling

In the FAQ of the Boomerang decompiler (which currently only decompiles to C-code) they make a brief mention that Visual Basic exes happen to include a lot of metadata, so a Visual Basic decompiler might be able to produce better source code for Visual Basic programs than what Boomerang can give you.  Since the program I'm trying to decompile might actually be a VB 6 program, do you know of any decompilers for VB6 exes?

(Don't worry this isn't for nefarious purposes.  I just have to create a data file this program parses, and getting a sense of the strategy it uses to parse the file will help get the file format right.)

Comment: See the [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414068/is-there-a-vb6-decompiler) [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678544/free-vb-6-0-decompiler) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406015/decompiler-for-visual-basic-6-program) on VB6 decompilers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try [VBReFormer](http://www.decompiler-vb.net/)

Comment: Thanks.  For me it generated an assembly listing, not VB code, but luckily before I was a professional programmer in high level languages I spent so much time as a teenager writing games in assembly that I can read x86 assembly listing just fine!  It DID pick up on all the VB function names, which is the important part for finding the right section of code to look in.

Answer (score 0):

[VB Decompiler](http://www.vb-decompiler.org) is another tool. And works fine too!)
[image: VB Decompiler]