# Legacy VB6 App won't start

Tags: vb6

I inherited a headache.  I have a small legacy (GUI) app that was developed 10 years ago and the VB6 source code is long gone.  It works currently on a couple of old XP PCs and I was asked to see if I could get it working on Windows 7 64bit.  Well… that was a no go, so I tried a 32bit version to verify that 64 wasn’t the issue and it didn’t work.  So I then created an XP virtual machine and it didn’t work either.  The issue is the same on all three environments.  You double click the .exe and nothing is displayed but when you look under task manager, it’s there and pegging the CPU.
I downloaded Dependency Walker and it seems that all the required dlls and OCX files are there.  Can anyone suggest anything else?  I’m really at a loss here.  Anything would be appreciated!

Comment: without source code, its not really a programming issue....

Comment: If someone knows of a decompiler that actually works or has seen this issue while developing/deploying their own apps it is.

Comment: There are existing questions about VB6 decompilers. In short, there don't seem to be any good ones. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414068/is-there-a-vb6-decompiler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678544/free-vb-6-0-decompiler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406015/decompiler-for-visual-basic-6-program

Answer (score 3):

The standard approach is to download and run [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), set it to filter just your executable, run your executable and ProcessMonitor will capture what DLLs/Files/ Registry settings are being used by your application.

Comment: +1, wish it could be more.  @user1443429
, for debugging VB6 COM component loading, this is a key step.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed you have the VB6 runtime files installed?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290887

I'm not sure if they are included in Win7 anymore and they were only in XP in one of the later service packs.

Comment: They are included and supported on Vista, 7, and 8.

Comment: I have.  I just cannot figure out how to make this thing work.  It opens up and just pegs the CPU.