# Finding ODBC connection name

Tags: database, vb6, odbc

**Situation:**

1. I have a program written in VB6
2. The source code of the program is not available
3. It connects to a database using ODBC connection string.
4. The vendor setup a connection name to the database when the program was first installed 6 years ago
5. My machine crashed, all the settings are gone!
6. The program vendor is out of business. Even they don't have the source of the program now.

**Question:**

Can I find the [ODBC connection name](http://i48.tinypic.com/15zktid.png) in anyway?

Comment: Who voted to close? Why is this not programming related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to catch the connection string your program is trying to open. You can find almost everything a program is doing, and you can filter what information is captured/displayed.

Comment: How can I use it to capture ODBC string? I have working knowledge in PE, but can't figure out how it can be used in this scenario.

Comment: It will tell you every reg key and file it tries to access.

Comment: At last I managed to find the string using PE! The method is: (1) Find the access database's password using MdbPassword Sniffer (NirSoft) (2) Dumped all strings using PE (3) Searched for the password in the file (4) Found connection string near the password text match. Your suggestion helped me a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've understood. What exactly happens when you try to run the program? Is the problem that the ODBC connection string was lost because the settings were lost when your machine crashed?

If so I would try the following.

- Look on a backup for the configuration file of the VB6 program. It may be an INI file.
- Do you know what the database is? Is it an Access file (*.MDB), SQL Server, or what? You may be able to [recreate](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) the connection string from scratch. You might have problems if you need to supply a password.
- Are you still in contact with anyone from the vendor? I'd have thought whoever originally wrote the program would be best able to help, and might be willing to do a couple of days consultancy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found the string using the method I described to Beaner. +10 for pointing out that connectionstring website! Priceless! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a [decompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414068/is-there-a-vb6-decompiler)?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably run an ODBC trace and then look in the log file to see what the attempted name was.  Run odbcad32.exe and go to the trace tab and turn it on.  Run your app and then look in the log file (probably at the SQLConnect call).

Comment: +1 for this suggestion. It doesn't show the connection string, though. :(

Comment: That's too bad.  I didn't try a trace with a connection string.  If you have a "strings" utility, you might just run it on the application binary and dump the output to a file.  A scan through it might show what the name is.  Or even a hex editor should reveal the connection string.  I just wrongly assumed the ODBC trace would show it.  Sorry about that.