# how to retrieve the source code from a dll written through VB6?

Tags: vb6, decompiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a vb6 decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414068/is-there-a-vb6-decompiler)

Is there any way that i can retrieve the source code from a dll written through VB6. There are no other files except the dll itself

Comment: No one has yet found a way to reverse the compilation process: to get back to source code from a compiled DLL. If you can figure this out, call your patent attorney right away because you'll become rich.

Comment: Of course there is, contact the owner and ask for a source code license.

Comment: @HansPassant: That is not always an option, the code maybe lost. He does say "retrieve"...

Comment: @Pete Wilson: your comment is misleading, is is *possible* to get source by decompiling.  You just never get the original, a HQ decompiler will get you code that can be compiled into a bin.  Pragmatically speaking, no Free Software HQ decompiler exists.  (Even the freeware offerings are barely usable)

Answer (score 1):

there are several options (although you never get the original source code and sometimes it ain't pretty if the DLL has been compiled to native code!)... see http://www.program-transformation.org/Transform/VisualBasicDecompilers.

For example http://www.vb-decompiler.org/products.htm

Answer (score 0):

Google search for "VB6 disassembler" revealed this product:  http://www.vb-decompiler.org/products.htm

I've never used it myself.

There is no equivalent of .Net ILDASM.exe for VB6 though, and the results from such disassembler products will not be as pretty as the original source code.