# How to break the .exe application?

Tags: vb6

I have requirment to create application based on exiting application.But we don't any document or source code of that exiting application.So, i would like to know how that application is working.For that is there any way to break .exe application ? looks like its created by VB.
Just i would like to see the program , Please advise is there any way to break .exe application and see the program ?

Comment: *Existing* application, perhaps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414068/is-there-a-vb6-decompiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is basically a decompiler. Depending upon how the program was compiled, you can recover various pieces, but not necessarily everything.

More details in the answers to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414068/is-there-a-vb6-decompiler)

Comment: VB decompiler showing method and functions only.Not source code.Is there any way to get source code ?