# Protect parts of my code by using a VB6 DLL

Tags: c#, vb6, obfuscation, source-code-protection

I have a C# desktop application.

There are some parts of my code where it needs to be in the client code as opposed to my server code which the client 'talks' to.

I have read a lot of stuff about protecting code and the general gist seems to be for client apps you cannot.  You can just make it difficult for them and if so it may not be worth the time and effort to do so.

A very simple idea i had was to put some of the code into a VB6 DLL and access it from my .net code.

Would this be worth any mileage?

Comment: I suppose the first question is 'why VB'? You will need to ship the whole runtime with it too. Why not C++?

Comment: rob- very good point.  should have thought about it a bit better lol. So, if i did use C++ would it other a better protection.Thanks :)

Comment: There are mechanisms that offer protection - however if a CPU can run your code it can be decompiled and understood.

Comment: Hi again Rob. Yes that was my conclusion as well.:( thanks

Comment: I think my question needs to be closed though..

Comment: The VB6 runtime is a protected part of the operating system in all supported versions of Windows, and has been installed with the OS even longer than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread [Is there a Visual Basic 6 decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414068/is-there-a-vb6-decompiler) indicates that there are VB6 decompilers, so I wouldnt think VB6 would give an adequate protection for your intellectual property.

Comment: VB6 decompilers are generally pretty worthless for a DLL compiled to native code.  This is why such software written in VB6 is considered *far more secure* than anything possible via .Net languages.

Comment: @Bob77 hi, that was what i heard too. apart from being able to look at string values the decompilers did not seem to give much else. That was why i looked at using it in the 1st place.  If Microsoft did native code compilation for desktop apps then i would obviously use that but at the moment they only support phone apps...