# Can I extract VB6.0 Source Code using its EXE File

Tags: vb6

I have an VB6.0 Application designed by a programmer. Unfortunately we are not able to reach this guy and we badly need to do some modifications in the application at the earliest.

The software was designed and complied on Windows XP device. We only have is EXE File.

I would appreciate if anybody could help me in extracting the source code using its EXE file.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is called "decompile". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414068/is-there-a-vb6-decompiler for example.

Comment: Thank chris. guess too many things to explore there. will come back to you......

Answer (score 0):

No. All MS programs have two  compilers. The first is language specific, the second is shared between all languages (C2.exe). So your program is very similar to a C++ program once made.

Compilers strip all names (programs use memory addresses, names are lost once translated).

Also compilers optimise. They throw away unused code, they optimise away functions, they optimise away stack frames. You turn optimisations on after debugging.

Comment: thanks for your clarification. though me not intended to give up early will try my luck. if found then definitely will post here. Thanks mate... :)

Comment: Start VB6, press F2, add your program as a reference (right click). If no error, then it's a COM program. Can you do whatever by subclassing the COM methods listed in Object Browser. Your code is mostly gone. Never to be recovered. The best you can get is a list of VB6's function calls the program makes.