# Understand VB6 disassemble code

Tags: vb6, disassembly

I have an old VB executable that has been used for a long time in my project. 
The current implementation of the application contains a debug window that's 
not needed any more.

Of course, the source code was lost and can not be modified.
My idea is to modify the HEX code of the instance that's opening the annoying debug window.

For that purpose, I use VB Decompiler by DotFix software, and I suppose that I found the code responsible for that instance. Unfortunately, I can't understand how it works.

Let's see the disassemble code:

```
  loc_8F420C: var_8A = 0
  loc_8F4219: If (Len(var_88) = &H30) Then
  loc_8F4225:   Call {3014B1BF-8A2C-23D7-B50400C24F280C20}.Method_arg_12 (var_88)
  loc_8F4233:   Call {3014B1BF-8A2C-23D7-B50400C24F280C20}.Method_arg_16 (var_108)
  loc_8F423D:   If CBool(var_108) Then
  loc_8F424D:     Me.Global.Unload Me
  loc_8F4258:   Else
  loc_8F425A:     var_8A = &HFF    
                  ...
  loc_8F43B0:   End If
  loc_8F43B3: Else
```

At the first sight **`var_108`** seems a bool variable that is the one setting the debug window. Can I implicitly put in **`loc_8F423D: If CBool(false/true) Then`** to stop this window from launching?

Can anyone explain to me what are those **`Call {#######-####-####-################}.Method_arg_##`** from above?

```
PEiD detect compiler:
Microsoft Visual Basic 5.0 / 6.0 [Overlay]
```

**Part 2:**
It took me a long time to get the new idea - the right one, possibly. Let's take a look at the assembly code:

```
004F420C: 70   FStI2 var_8A <- loc_8F420C: var_8A = 0
```

Looks like `loc_8F4219: If (Len(var_88) = &H30) Then`

```
004F420F: 6C   ILdRf var_88
004F4212: 4A   FnLenStr Len()
004F4213: F5   LitI4: 48 (0x30)
```

Let's find the next code snippets:

```
004F4218: C7   EqI4 =
004F4219: 1C   BranchF 004F43B3
```

Our Call methods looks like :

```
004F421C: 6C   ILdRf var_88 < - (var_88) from Call
004F421F: 22   ImpAdLdPr
004F4222: 58   MemLdPr
004F4225: 0D   VCallHresult  var_88.vtable[12] <- Method_arg_12
004F422A: 04   FLdRfVar var_108 <- (var_108) possible CALL/BACK
004F422D: 22   ImpAdLdPr
004F4230: 58   MemLdPr
004F4233: 0D   VCallHresult  var_108.vtable[16] <- Method_arg_16
004F4238: 6C   ILdRf var_108 <- (var_108) 70% sure is RESPONSE(true/false)
```

And now the most interesting parts of that annoying P-Code&Assembly, we find the if instance that verifies if the Debug Windows is needed. If we look at P-Code we can see that if has the form:

```
loc_8F423D:   If CBool(var_108) Then
loc_8F424D:     Me.Global.Unload Me
loc_8F4258:   Else
loc_8F425A:     var_8A = &HFF
```

And now look at the Address - if is true execute address **00F424D / 8F424D** else jump outside to **004F4258**

```
004F423B: FC52 CBoolI4
004F423D: 1C   BranchF 004F4258
004F4240: 6C   ILdRf param_8
004F4243: FD9C FStAdNoPop
004F4247: 05   ImpAdLdRf
004F424A: 24   NewIfNullPr GLOBAL
004F424D: 0D   VCallHresult Global._Unload(object As IDispatch)
004F4252: 1A   FFree1Ad var_90
004F4255: 1E   Branch 004F43B0
004F4258: loc_004F423D
004F4258: F4   LitI2_Byte: 255 (True)
```

Possibly, if I change the `004F423D: 1C   BranchF 004F4258` so that it points to another address `004F424D`, logically that might do the trick.

> `004F423D: 1C   BranchF 004F424D`

---

Now I'm trying to find that address with **OllyDbg** - to test if that helps. If I succeed I will write part 3.

Does anyone have some other ideas?

Comment: Just for reference, there are various questions about [available VB6 decompilers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414068/is-there-a-vb6-decompiler) although you have found one already.

Comment: I've never used that decompiler product (or any other) but your reasoning sounds correct about the dissassembly code. I am not sure how you would go about patching the binary EXE in the way you describe. Another approach might be to automatically close the window. You might be able to do this without modifying the VB6 EXE. You could have a wrapper EXE that launches the VB6 EXE, finds the window handle of the debug window, and then sends a close message (WM_CLOSE).