# Can I open an installed application in visual studio for debugging?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have an old installed application it is probably a VB6 application that i need to revise and make it a .net but the problem is some computations of quantities are hard to solve. what is your suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Visual Basic 6 decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414068/is-there-a-visual-basic-6-decompiler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `decompiling` is what you're looking for.

Take a look at this threat:
[Is there a Visual Basic 6 decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414068/is-there-a-vb6-decompiler)