# Decompiler visual basic 6.0 to source code

Tags: vb6

I lost the source code from a project. I've used VB-Decompiler but it does not give the source code.

How can i decompile from vb6.exe to source code?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you need VB4 or VB6?

Comment: Sorry, that was my typo. I have a vb6.exe

Comment: There are a number of similar questions on this site.  Here's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/414068/5162073) to get you started.