# How can I get source code from exe files?

Tags: vb6, exe, decompiling

A few days ago, I have formated my disk and I have lost all datas.
Now I have only two VB6 exe files and I want source code from those.
Is there any way to recover source code from VB6 exe files?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot*, in general, retrieve source code from an executable as it's a one-way transformation from in this case visual basic to binary machine code.  If you compiled your binary with debug information you have more information available.  You can of course obtain assembly and there are a class of tools that is called decompilers that ease transformation to a high-level language like C.  See for example https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8038/exe-to-c-source-code-decompiler.  Sorry.

Comment: In oversimplified layman's terms: you're asking how to recreate a cow out of mince.

Comment: This answer is not the whole truth. There is a VB5/VB6 decompiler (you just have to google for "vb decompiler". The product claims to recover most of the code (form the p-code) and some of the code for native execs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414068/is-there-a-visual-basic-6-decompiler