# How to decompile the vb6 executable file(exe)?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, vb6, reverse-engineering

I am given a list of old exe files where the original source code are lost.

While i am able to extract code from some of the exe files using tools like
DotPeek or ILSpy or JustDecompile.

I see a couple of them failed to decompile. I am getting the below similar error

[image]

What would be the next step I need to do to extract code or do reverse engineer?

kindly let me know.

Comment: what kind of assembly are they? are they .net ones or something else?

Comment: Its hard to tell but I am seeing MZ at the beginning if I open the exe in notepad.

Comment: All exe files ever made start with MZ

Comment: Are you ONLY asking about VB6 or are you asking about multiple different technologies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Visual Basic 6 decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414068/is-there-a-visual-basic-6-decompiler)

Comment: I see those exe files made around 2015. so cant confirm which technologies are used. but I believe all exe files are compiled using microsoft related coding. kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no CLR header then it is probably not a .NET application and you would have to go deeper.

Start with something like [PEiD](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/PEiD), it should hopefully tell you if it is packed and basic guessing of the compiler used. If it is VB6 or Delphi you might want to look for specific de-compilers for those, otherwise go back to basic disassembly.

Both [IDA](https://hex-rays.com/ida-free/) and [Ghidra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghidra) can be used for free...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tool that automatically tries to identify a file. It takes an "educated guess" based on similar files analyzed and community contributed identifications *(I contributed some definitions)*. For executables, it tries to name the programming language/compiler, too: [TrID](https://mark0.net/onlinetrid.html). If the file is too large for the online analyzer, there's a link to download a (Windows) standalone version. *(Disclaimer:)* I know Marco as a regular and knowledgeable contributor from a programming forum where this project started. It has been featured in a [Computer Forensic article](https://www.heise.de/hintergrund/Tatort-Internet-Ferngesteuert-1320475.html?seite=all) by the renowned German computer magazine c't.